# AWS DynamoDB TTL

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm having trouble getting AWS DynamoDB TTL to work. I set my ttl attribute to `ttl`, and set `ttl` on all of my rows to `0`. I did this 6 days ago but I still have rows in my db with ttl set to `0`.

Does setting ttl to 0 not work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A TTL value of `0` doesn't work, according to this:

> Items with an expiration time greater than 5 years in the past are not deleted.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start.html

The TTL value is the time in Unix Epoch format, where `0` means `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` -- more than 5 years in the past.